# PowerShell WinForm: Enable button if one or more checkboxes are checked otherwise disable button

Tags: winforms, powershell

Should be pretty straight forward but cant work out the logic. Below is the code I currently have which sort of works but the only problem is if more than one checkboxes are checked and you uncheck one the button disables, I need the button to remain enabled as long as there is one or more checkbox checked. I've also tried various convoluted If and Elseif statements but nothing I've tried changes this behaviour.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '170,191'
$Form.text                       = "Scheduler"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$MonCheckBox                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$MonCheckBox.text                = "Monday"
$MonCheckBox.AutoSize            = $false
$MonCheckBox.width               = 95
$MonCheckBox.height              = 20
$MonCheckBox.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,30)
$MonCheckBox.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$TueCheckBox                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$TueCheckBox.text                = "Tuesday"
$TueCheckBox.AutoSize            = $false
$TueCheckBox.width               = 95
$TueCheckBox.height              = 20
$TueCheckBox.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,50)
$TueCheckBox.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$WedCheckBox                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$WedCheckBox.text                = "Wednesday"
$WedCheckBox.AutoSize            = $false
$WedCheckBox.width               = 95
$WedCheckBox.height              = 20
$WedCheckBox.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,70)
$WedCheckBox.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$ThuCheckBox                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$ThuCheckBox.text                = "Thursday"
$ThuCheckBox.AutoSize            = $false
$ThuCheckBox.width               = 95
$ThuCheckBox.height              = 20
$ThuCheckBox.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,90)
$ThuCheckBox.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$FriCheckBox                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$FriCheckBox.text                = "Friday"
$FriCheckBox.AutoSize            = $false
$FriCheckBox.width               = 95
$FriCheckBox.height              = 20
$FriCheckBox.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,110)
$FriCheckBox.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$SchedButton                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$SchedButton.text                = "Schedule"
$SchedButton.width               = 60
$SchedButton.height              = 30
$SchedButton.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,134)
$SchedButton.Font                = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
$SchedButton.Autosize            = $true
$SchedButton.Enabled             = $false

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($MonCheckBox,$TueCheckBox,$WedCheckBox,$ThuCheckBox,$FriCheckBox,$SchedButton))

$MonCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged({$SchedButton.Enabled = $MonCheckBox.Checked})
$TueCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged({$SchedButton.Enabled = $TueCheckBox.Checked})
$WedCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged({$SchedButton.Enabled = $WedCheckBox.Checked})
$ThuCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged({$SchedButton.Enabled = $ThuCheckBox.Checked})
$FriCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged({$SchedButton.Enabled = $FriCheckBox.Checked})

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$Form.controls.AddRange(@($MonCheckBox, $TueCheckBox, $WedCheckBox, $ThuCheckBox, $FriCheckBox, $SchedButton))

Function Test-AnyButtonChecked {
    if (
        $MonCheckBox.Checked -or
        $TueCheckBox.Checked -or
        $WedCheckBox.Checked -or
        $ThuCheckBox.Checked -or
        $FriCheckBox.Checked
    ) {
        $SchedButton.Enabled = $true
    }
    else {
        $SchedButton.Enabled = $false
    }
}

$MonCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
$TueCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
$WedCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
$ThuCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })
$FriCheckBox.add_CheckedChanged( { Test-AnyButtonChecked })

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```